# document.getElementById() keeps returning NULL - how to find value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am using one of those vulnerable practice sites on Kali Linux and when I inspected the source page I noticed the following variable `var pathName = document.getElementById("path")` The value of `pathName` is hidden and it is up to me to find it as these sites are there for people to practice their ethical hack skills

So in the Chrome Web Browser console, I type in `document.getElementById("path").value` but I keep getting return `null`. I don't understand why, like do I need to do like `window.ontop`?

Any help would be great!

Comment: Is `#path` an `<input />`? Otherwise it's not going to have a `.value`...

Comment: Then perhaps that element is not there any more. Or the ID of it has changed.

Comment: @VLAZ Damn it! How do I find the value

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol all i see is that variable `path` being declared

Comment: You could just use a debugger, I guess. I'm not sure how you'd do it post-load, as I don't know the application.

Comment: `path` is not supposed to be a variable, instead is should be a id in input. It should be like `<input id="path"/>`, is something like there in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If `document.getElementById("path").value` returns null, your element was found.  It might not be an `input` element, so might not contain a `value` field.

Try typing `JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("path"))` into the console to inspect the object.

Also try `document.getElementById("path").outerHTML` to see the attributes and children.

Or just `document.getElementById("path")` and open the tree to view the internals.

Comment: If element selector is returning `null` what do you expect from `JSON.stringify(null)`?

Comment: op does not know what field the value is in.   this will return the properties of the object. the element obviously exists.

Comment: "*obviously exists"* no, it's not obvious. The line cited is there but we don't know if the variable `pathName` is ever used, so perhaps the element *existed* in the past or it could even be a typo but it doesn't cause any issues, so it's still there. Moreover, the element could have existed during loading but was changed/removed later, so it is not there post-load.

Comment: `document.getElementById("path").value` would not return null if the element did not exiist.

Comment: And it wouldn't return `null` even if it exists. We do not have enough information to know if `document.getElementById("path")` returns `null` (which is normal if the element doesn't exist) or `document.getElementById("path").value` returns `null` (which it cannot do, unless it's the literal string `"null"`). Your answer is not useful. It's at best left as a comment.

Comment: @StevenSpungin it's entirely possible that OP *is* getting the exception and is saying "it returns null" meaning he got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` - this is certainly a problem for many beginner JS developers when they get `cannot get X of null` or `cannot get X of undefined` and they have an expression in the form of `a.b.c`, they assume it's `c` which is respectively `null` or `undefined` not `a` or `b`. So, YET AGAIN, we have no information whether `getElementById` or `.value` is null.

Comment: OP posted wrong subject.  The Question is that the DOM element is found but OP does not know what property or node the value is stored in.  It is probably not an `input` element.

Comment: An `input` with no `value` would return an empty string - `document.createElement("input").value`, while an element with no `value` property would return `undefined` - `document.createElement("div").value`. Although some elements might return something a bit different (I know `li` elements return an integer in FF). But overall, I'm not convinced that OP is getting the correct element but it simply doesn't have a `value` property hence the result is `null`. Still, your edit does make it much more useful as a way to find what is happening.

Comment: It keeps returning `null`

Comment: @AndresSaarleemzczc so `document.getElementById("path").outerHTML ` returns null?

Comment: Also, are you able to put a breakpoint on the line `pathName = document.getElementById("path")` and have the debugger stop there?

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure you have an `input` in DOM with `id="path"` attribute value.

For example - 
`<input id="path">`

If that is not present in the DOM then `getElementById` will always return null.

You can open Chrome-Dev Tool and search this `#path` in Elements tab. That should highlight that input, if it is not then you are targeting wrong element.

[image]

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("path")` seems to be returning a `HTMLCollection`. Not sure, how I would proceed to obtain the hidden value of path